# How to change label size according to device Text Size - Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, string, label

I change my text size like following image.

But my app doesn't change the the font size.

Have any idea to me?

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = YES
label.text = string
```

[image]

Comment: [Follow this religiously.](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-type/)

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 10 onwards you can support dynamic font sizes using one line :)

Change your

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

to use,

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
```

You can specify the font style you need for your label :)

Refer : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619030-preferredfont

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution. Just add below lines-

**SWIFT 3:**

```
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1    //or whatever suits your need
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true    
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
label.numberOfLines = 0
```